# Counting Demisemiquavers (32nd notes)

Tags: practice, learning, rhythm

I was a little surprised that this question wasn't already asked here - perhaps I missed it/it's off topic. I'm trying to write out the count for a piece in common time (I can barely read sheets) and I have no idea what syllabic notation to use for the 32nd notes/demisemiquavers. From what I recall, "1 e & a" is used for semiquavers. All I've found online are people saying you simply don't count shorter notes with these syllables, and I haven't found anything for the Eastman Counting System either. Not counting them seems a bit unsatisfying for me, because you might also end up with hemidemisemiquavers...

Comment: Mentally double each note value, put it into 2/4 and count 1e&a?

Comment: At some point you have to move from consciously counting to internalizing the rhythm. That just takes time and practice :-)

Comment: If you want to count out the rhythm *slowly*, take the main beats as 8th-notes  (or 16th-notes if the rhythm contains 64th-notes) with 8 or 16 beats in the bar instead of 4. As @CarlWitthoft said, eventually you will learn to just internalize reading the rhythm, rather than counting it out loud.

Comment: well as Adam Neely said: count "how to count thirty-second notes"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you don't count *every single* note, because they are really fast and it would be really tough. Instead, you break them in groups of two. You count them as you would count 16th notes (semiquavers), but with two beats on each hit:

[image]

[Image source](http://www.freedrumlessons.com/drum-lessons/thirty-second-notes.php)

Another video which states the same:

`1 e and a`, but two notes on each syllable